# range - how to select new inserted node automatically?

Tags: javascript, select, range

newNode = document.createElement("span");
    newNode.innerHTML = 'example';
    range.insertNode(newNode);

i insert new node. is there way, how to automatically select this newNode (as it appears on page, it is not selected) ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
range.selectNodeContents(newNode);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```